# Becoming an expert with accumulative hours of practice much less than the average expert?

Tags: learning, experimental-psychology, performance, expertise

Anders Ericsson's work is famous for creating the idea of "deliberate practice" and its creation of experts, but Anders also talks about how long hours are inevitable in becoming an expert. Let's examine this on the standard of running. In 1960 a less than 5 minute mile was impossible, but now it's impressive but having a closer to 4 minute flat mile run is more impressive. We can maybe assume people didn't train as long as people do now to achieve that which would support Anders, but what if the variance in time spent training between 1960 runners and now is about the same, just that our training methodologies have allowed runners to easily surpass that speed. My question is what allows someone to become an expert in shorter time? What features of training methods IN ANY field (not just running) allows someone to acquire expertise in a field faster than other methodologies? Can we evaluate such methodologies?